# Callling a wcf within android app and passing listview selected item

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I know I posted a question the other day about how should I be passing a selected android listview item to the a wcf serivce application. I am just trying to use the simplest approach to get things working. I am having the problem of getting the towns from the selected county using a wcf. I have a county table with id and county. In a towns table I have id, name and countyid.

Here is my wcf service application:

```
[OperationContract]
Festivalwrapper GetTownDataByCounty(int? id);

public Festivalwrapper GetTownDataByCounty(int? id)
{
    Festivalwrapper returnType = new Festivalwrapper();
    using (azureDBDataContext c = new azureDBDataContext())
    {
        returnType.TownList = (from town in c.Towns
                               where town.CountyID.Equals(id)
                               select new TownVM()
                               {
                                   ID = town.ID,
                                   Name = town.Name,
                               }).ToList();
    }
    return returnType;
}
```

Here is my `OnItemClick` for my first activity:

```
     public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
     {
        var selectedValue = parent.GetItemIdAtPosition(position);
        //InitializeDataTownById(int position);
        var Intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SelectLocationActivity));
        // selectedValue should already be a string but...
        Intent.PutExtra("Name", selectedValue.ToString());
        StartActivity(Intent);
     }
```

And my second activity:

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light")]
public class SelectLocationActivity : Activity
{
    private DataTransferProcClient _client;
    TextView _getTownsTextView;
    ListView _listView;
    public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://10.0.2.2:3190/DataTransferProc.svc");
    //private int id;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //var id = Intent.GetStringExtra("position");

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.selectLocation);

        _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvTowns);
        //_listView.OnItemClickListener = this;
        _listView.FastScrollEnabled = true;

        _getTownsTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getTownsTextView);

        InitializeDataTownById();
    }

    #region InitializeDataTown
    private void InitializeDataTownById()
    {
        var id = Intent.GetStringExtra("Name");
        int value;
        int.TryParse(id, out value);

        if (id != null)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
            _client = new DataTransferProcClient(binding, EndPoint);
            _client.GetTownDataByCountyCompleted += ClientOnDataTransferProcCompleted;
            _client.GetTownDataByCountyAsync(id);
        }
        //_client.Close ();
    }
    #endregion

    #region CreateBasicHttp
    private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 67108864,
        };

        binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483646,
            MaxStringContentLength = 5242880,
        };

        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        return binding;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ClientOnDataTransferProcCompleted
    //test connection to wcf, if doesn't work, you'll get an error
    private void ClientOnDataTransferProcCompleted(object sender, GetTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        string msg = null;

        if (getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
        {
            msg = getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
            msg += getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Error.InnerException;
            RunOnUiThread(() => _getTownsTextView.Text = msg);
        }
        else if (getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
        {
            msg = "Request was cancelled.";
            RunOnUiThread(() => _getTownsTextView.Text = msg);
        }
        else
        {
            msg = getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Result.ToString();
            TestAndroid.Festivalwrapper testHolder = getTownDataByCountyCompletedEventArgs.Result;
            List<string> holder = testHolder.TownList.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();

            /*foreach (TestAndroid.CountyVM item in TestHolder.CountyList)
            {
                holder.Add (item.Name);
            }*/

            RunOnUiThread(() => _listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, holder));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

I am also having a problem converting the string into an int. I am getting errors at : _client.GetTownDataByCountyAsync(id);

1. Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' (CS1503)
2. Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'DataTransferProcClient.GetTownDataByCountyAsync(int)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string num;
int num2;

num = "2";

// method 1 - will throw Exception if num is not a parsable int
num2 = int.Parse(num);

// method 2 - will not throw exception - if success is true num2 will contain the parsed int
bool success = int.TryParse(num,out num2);
```

Comment: Ah I see, but other than that am I doing everything else right @Jason?

Comment: After looking at your code again I see that you are using TryParse() but you are passing the input (id) instead of the output (value) when you call _client.GetTownDataByCountyAsync(id);

Comment: Thanks Jason, I got it to work. Only thing is, my listview starts at 0. Is there any way I can get the listview to start at 1?